# How to make sure to insert songs in songhistory database from shoutcast history without duplicates when date changes?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the last 10 played songs from a shoutcast server and want to insert them into my database in order to keep track of which song played at a specific date and time.

Here is the table structure:

```
`id_played`     int(11)        AUTO_INCREMENT
`date_played`   date
`time_played`   time
`artist`        varchar(255)
`title`         varchar(255)
```

And this is my code to insert the songs into the table:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

for($i = 0; $i < $songsCount; $i++) {
    $stmtGetExisting = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_played FROM played WHERE date_played = ? AND time_played = ? AND artist = ? AND title = ?");
    $stmtGetExisting->bind_param("ssss", $date, $times[$i], $artists[$i], $titles[$i]);
    $stmtGetExisting->execute();
    $stmtGetExisting->store_result();
    $rows = $stmtGetExisting->num_rows;

    if($rows == 0) {
        $stmtInsertSong = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO played SET date_played = ?, time_played = ?, artist = ?, title = ?");
        $stmtInsertSong->bind_param("ssss", $date, $times[$i], $artists[$i], $titles[$i]);
        $stmtInsertSong->execute();
    }
}
```

I want to run this script with a cronjob to automatically keep a history of all played songs so this script will be executed very frequently.

Most of the time it is working great but if the date changes from let's say 2015-02-23 to 2015-02-24 the songs that played right before the date change
will be inserted again but with the new date.

What is the best way to make sure that songs that played right before a date change won't get inserted again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like is happening is that you are getting the time that the song was played from the server, but using the current date as the date it was played. If that is the case, you can modify your script as follows:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H-i-s");

for($i = 0; $i < $songsCount; $i++) {
    //since the time is was played would be later then the current time (only time, not
    //datetime) you can check if the pulled time is greater then the current time

    if($time < $times[$i]) continue;

    $stmtGetExisting = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_played FROM played WHERE date_played = ? AND time_played = ? AND artist = ? AND title = ?");
    $stmtGetExisting->bind_param("ssss", $date, $times[$i], $artists[$i], $titles[$i]);
    $stmtGetExisting->execute();
    $stmtGetExisting->store_result();
    $rows = $stmtGetExisting->num_rows;

    if($rows == 0) {
        $stmtInsertSong = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO played SET date_played = ?, time_played = ?, artist = ?, title = ?");
        $stmtInsertSong->bind_param("ssss", $date, $times[$i], $artists[$i], $titles[$i]);
        $stmtInsertSong->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the case. I have a question about your if-statement: If I have a song played at 19:00:00 and execute my script at 19:05:00 wouldn't the song be ignored even though it's valid or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You are correct. The condition should have been < instead of >. I have updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: I tested it over the night and it is working correctly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only the first date a song was played, I'd put an index on artist+title columns and use a "ON DUPLICATE KEY" mysql condition that will update a counter. In this way you can also remove the select query to check for record existence, as the index will check it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need three tables to properly handle this kind of requirement. The first table shall only contain artist attributes, the second only song attributes and the third one only execution attributes. The primary key of artist table should be either the artist name or the key from your external provider. The key of the song table must be a compound key including the artist pk and the song name. Artist must be a foreign key. The key for the execution must be a compound key using the song pk plus the date time of execution. I'll try to design it after getting to my computer.